# Blender 2.83 object selection not working correctly

Tags: modeling

I just downloaded version 2.83 and am following a tutorial, but things aren't working like how the tutorial is. When I select an object it doesn't highlight completely like in the tute; only the outline does. When in Edit Mode, I can't see the edges or the faces, but can see the vertices for some reason. I played around in the Overlay box, but it hasn't helped. I'm sure it's probably just some quick setting somewhere. Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

when you are in the edit mode press 1 for vertex selection, 2 for edge selection or 3 for the face selection. Try to press alt+H in edit mode it will unhide everything. If it does not help please provide me with the sreenshot

Comment: The 1, 2, and 3 part was actually in the tutorial. The alt+H didn't help. Don't know how to add a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar issue, the way I solve that was to go *Files* top left, scroll down to *Defaults*, under it you will find *Save Startup File* and *Load Factory Settings*.

Click on *Load Factory Settings* and it should definitely solve it.